# Was this place the Island?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In the final scene of TFA we see

> Rey, Chewie and BB-8 flying in the Falcon to the Island where Luke has been for the past 30 or so years

But earlier

> When Rey was being interrogated by Kylo Ren he says that he sees an Ocean and an Island that Rey pictures when she falls asleep

However,

> The map appeared to only have the location of the planet but not the exact place on that planet that Luke and/or the Jedi Temple would be. Additionally when Rey sees the Island she seems to recognize it and since the whole planet seemed to be filled with islands unless we are to assume that Rey, Chewie and BB-8 stopped at each one or that they made an extremely lucky first guess (and we all know there's no such thing as luck) could Rey have perhaps been picturing/daydreaming about this Island the whole time?

Comment: I certainly assumed so.

Comment: Yup I guess this is a dupe, thought I had searched enough but I guess not.

Comment: He wasn't there for 30 years, or he would not have trained Kylo Ren ;)